# Patch request in functional component react

Tags: reactjs, json, api, react-hooks, patch

Have a functional component called toggle, need to add a patch request so every time the toggle fires the change gets updated (show/hide) in UI and db.
Is the only way to do is to use hoots useState?

here is some code for reference

```
const ToggleStats = ({ label, value, onChange }) => {
  const toggled = !!value


  const handleToggle = () => {
    onChange(!toggled)
    // TODO when the toggle gets clicked a request gets send to update the bd (show/hide)
    api.patch(`admin/admin/institutions/id/?with_deleted=true`, { body })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ })
      })
  }

  return (
    <Toggle
      label={label}
      labelPosition='left'
      labelStyle={styles.label}
      iconStyle={styles.ripple}
      thumbSwitchedStyle={styles.toggle}
      trackSwitchedStyle={styles.toggleBackround}
      onToggle={handleToggle}
    />
  )
}

ToggleStats.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to add argument to `handleToggle(x)` function. See if you are getting on/off state, if you are concerned about using useState.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear but I am guessing you are just trying to use useState to manage show or hide.

```
const Switch = ({isOn, handleToggle}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        checked={isOn}
        onChange={handleToggle}
        className="react-switch-checkbox"
        id={`react-switch-new`}
        type="checkbox"
      />
      <label className="react-switch-label" htmlFor={`react-switch-new`}>
        <span className={`react-switch-button`} />
      </label>
    </>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [show, setshow] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="app">
        <Switch isOn={show} handleToggle={() => setshow(!show)} />
      </div>
      {show ? 'Toggled' : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In my example you can see I manage the show state in the parent app component by using the react hook useState. On click of the toggle now sets show as either true or false and I can now use that state to run logic in my case a ternary operator which displays the text "Toggled on the screen.

Comment: i am using React 15.4.1 looks like useState hook is not being supported by this version of React. is there any other way around this, should i be changing it into class component instead?